# Converting Arrow to Parquet and vice versa in java

Tags: java, parquet, apache-arrow, parquet-mr

I have been looking at ways to convert `arrow` to `parquet` and vice versa in Java.

Even though the Python library for `arrow` has full support for the mentioned conversion, I can hardly find any documentation for the same in Java.

Has anyone come across such feature in `arrow/parquet`  Java libraries?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a native Java reader that is part of Arrow.  [There has been some recent discussion on creating one and the incubating Apache Iceberg project might also have one](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@arrow.apache.org:lte=1M:parquet)

[Dremio](https://github.com/dremio/dremio-oss/blob/master/sabot/kernel/src/main/java/com/dremio/exec/store/parquet/UnifiedParquetReader.java) has some code that potentially does the conversion

The core parquet-mr project also appears to have [code for conversion](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-arrow).